# Invoking custom annotation using Spring AOP

Tags: spring, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

I searched the web for a clear example on how to invoke my custom method annotation using Spring AOP but   couldn't find a clear example.

I am building a framework to inject a user profile in the context when certain methods on any POJO is called.

The framework API should be invoked via a custom method annotation, say `@RunAsAdmin`. I can build the annotation part and parser, my question is what is the best way to invoke my parser when the annotated method is called.

We are using Spring 3.0 and would like to know what is the best practice to configure Spring framework to understand those methods annotated with specific annotation and invoke my annotation handler (parser).

Any example or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intercepting a call on any annotated Spring bean method is straightforward, see the example below. 
Intercepting a call on a POJO is not possible by definition - you have to return a proxy instead. 
That is, you should implement a factory for these POJOs that will return proxies instead of real POJOs. You might use ProxyFactoryBean http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactoryBean.html for this.

```
//intercepting a call to any method annotated with @com.yours.RunAsAdmin of any Spring-managed bean
@Component @Aspect class RunAsAdminAspect {
    @Autowired 
    private YourRunAsAdminHandler handler;

    @Before("@annotation(com.yours.RunAsAdmin)")
    public void doRunAsAdmin() {
        handler.grantAdminRightsToCurrentUser(); //your real stuff
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, will go with the Spring managed bean using your example. What should go into my Spring context configuration? Is this all I need to add: `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`

Comment: Inside doRunAsAdmin method, is it possible to get handle of which method is about to be invoked?

Comment: you just need to change the method like public void doRunAsAdmin(JoinPoint joinpoint) than inside this you can get the invoked method like MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
Method method = signature.getMethod();

Comment: Thanks varun, that complements the answer!